# Thread 1: Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: ios, swift

I have my Messages custom class which is declared like this:

```
class Message: SBDBaseMessage {

    var text : String?
    var date: Date?

    init(text: String, date: Date) {
        super.init()
        self.text = text
        self.date = date
    }
}
```

Note: `SBDBaseMessage` is a custom message type of `SendBird` messaging framework.

Then, I have an empty array declared like this:

```
var messages: [Message] = [Message]()
```

And in the below block of code I got this crash message (on the second line) ->

> Thread 1: Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array
>   Element type

Here is the code:

```
func sendMessage() {
    if let channel = self.groupChannel {
        channel.sendUserMessage(textView.text) { (message, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            let newMessage: Message = Message(text: (message?.message)!, date: Date())
            self.messages.append(newMessage)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The message here is a `SBDUserMessage` which inherits from the `SBDBaseMessage`.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the crash is produced in this place exactly? The issue in question happens when bridging from Objective-C `NSArray` to Swift `Array`, but in this case there is no `NSArray`. Can you post a larger code snippet? Perhaps entire method containing the code you posted?

Comment: You mention that the message in the failing code block is a `SBDUserMessage` - is this a different class from your own `Message` class (which inherits from `SBDBaseMessage`). The message to append will have to be exactly the same class as that used when declaring the array.

Comment: @Chris I think OP meant the `message` parameter passed to `Message` constructor. `SBDUserMessage` does indeed contain a `message` property which is `NSString`

Comment: @mag_zbc Ah ok, thanks.

Comment: Sure, @mag_zbc, I've updated the question and added a larger code snippet

Comment: The crash occurs on this line: `self.messages.append(newMessage)`

Comment: Can you provide more about the type of the `message` object that you used to create instance of your `Message` type? What is the `message?.message` here?

Comment: @nayem, message?.message is an optional string, which I get from the server side. The message object is of type `SBDUserMessage`, which inherits from `SBDBaseMessage` - the type of my Message class

Comment: Put a print statement or try to debug the `newMessage` object before appending to the array. See if the `newMessage` object is created properly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the reason of this error. 
My `messages` array was being appended in another block of code with `SBDUserMessages`, and I wasn't cast them as exact type of message (`as! SBDUserMessage`).

The debugging really helped a lot. At some point I decided to call before the `self.messages.append(newMessage)` (where the crash actually occured), the messaged.removeAll(), and after that I've found out that everything works fine.